# Vite : Application works on localhost:5173 but not on 127.0.0.1:5173

Tags: reactjs, express, vite

My Vite.js application works normally on http://localhost:5173/ but when I am using http://127.0.0.1:5173/ the app does not work.

I am using an Intel Mac (MacOs: Ventura 13.0.1).

When I tried creating a normal react app, then http://localhost:3000 and [127.0.0.1:3000](http://127.0.0.1:3000) both are working the same.

Tried searching a few stackoverflow posts where they asked me run

`sudo nano /etc/hosts`

And the following line to the end of the file:

`127.0.0.1       myapp.local`

But that does not solve the issue as well.

My /etc/hosts file:

[image]

Comment: `vite` version?

Comment: The latest one: 4.0.0

Answer (score 12):

I was trying to reach my app from a different PC on the same local network. As far as I can tell Vite denies access to its host by default. Also, it tells us:

> Network: use --host to expose

So I added the `--host` flag into scripts in the `package.json` file as below:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "vite --host",
  "build": "tsc && vite build",
  "preview": "vite preview"
}
```

And it worked for me.
I've made a few screenshots for your convenience:

- Vite saying to use `--host` to expose

  [image]
- Place where I put the `--host` flag

  [image]

Reference: https://www.amitmerchant.com/expose-local-vite-instance-to-the-network

Comment: I think it's a much cleaner to instead change `vite.config.js`, by setting `server.port: true`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `myapp.local` to `localhost` in the `/etc/hosts` file, it should fix it

Comment: That line already exists. Please check the screenshot added just now.